# Better way of validating the request URI with a route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I am using conditional logic for redirects if you hit a certain route. Problem 1 the current way I'm doing it doesn't allow for a parameter to pass through the route so it will error out instead of just checking if the route matches. Problem 2 this method is sloppy and cumbersome. I really need to solve problem 1, I can live without cleaning it up but I would really like to.

Currently I'm doing something like this

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class myMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($user = Auth::user()){
            // Do some stuff
        } else {
            if(
               $request->getUri() != route('login') &&
               $request->getUri() != route('password.request') &&
               $request->getUri() != route('password.reset', null) //<-- This doesn't work because a parameter isn't properly given, want ANY param here
              )
            { 
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('warning', 'Please Login to access restricted area.');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I would like to this in a cleaner fashion, but still be able to reference the "name" of the route if possible in case the URI ever changes for some reason.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here; why don't you use the built in authentication scaffold? Try it out on an empty laravel project; run `php artisan make:auth` and see how it's supposed to be setup. It contains everything you are after. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication - see introduction

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see where you're coming from. It would be nice to do something similar for other means though but I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something that Laravel already offers.

There are two pieces of middleware, `auth` and `guest` that require a login, or no login. The best way to use these would be in a group.

```php
$router->middleware('auth:user')->group(function (Router $router) {
    // Your routes that require a user to be logged in
});

$router->middleware('guest:user')->group(function (Router $router) {
    // Your routes that require a user not be logged in
});
```

The `:user` part of the middleware specifies the guard, and can be omitted if you only have one guard.

Though the above is 100% definitely what you need for your particular use case, there is a better way to check whether the route is what you want, and that is the `routeIs()` method on the request object.

So to replace your if statement in your code it'd be:

```php
if ($request->routeIs('login', 'password.*')) {
    // Code
}
```

This will return true if the current route has the name `login` or its name starts with `password.`.

I would like to stress that the `auth` and `guest` middleware groups are definitely what you should do, but I added this bit as I feel like that was the functionality you were looking for.

Two answers for the price of one, enjoy.